# Combine an Image File with an Audio File

Tags: php

I have a requirement in my PHP site to join an image(jpg or png) with an audio(wav) and the output should be a video (like mpeg ,mp4 or wav itself).

Is there any tool available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) could do that quite easily. You can create a video from a set of images (in your case, only one) and attach audio to it. Just have a look at the documentation.